# HP Photosmart C7280 showing error for ink cartridge even after being replaced

Tags: printing, printer, hp-photosmart

The printer is displaying Cannot print - replace the following empty ink cartridge(s) to resume printing (Light Cyan).

First, the ink cartridge is not empty, but changed anyway with a new cartridge.  The printer still returns the same message.  It is like the system is not recognizing that there is ink.  Any ideas on what to do next?

Comment: Is it a HP ink cartridge?

Answer (score 1):

Some steps you should try:

1. Turn off the printer. Disconnect the power supply and wait for a few seconds, just to be sure. Then turn it back on. Often a reboot fixes most printer issues.
2. If that doesn't help, open the printer and remove the cyan cadridge. Make sure that both the chip and the connectors are perfectly clean. Re-insert the cadridge and check.
3. If the error is still appearing, remove all cadridges from the printer, clean them, and insert them back. You might even do a restart of the printer again before inserting back.
4. When the error still appears, try to reset your printer to factory defaults:

   1. Unplug the power supply while the printer is ON.
   2. Press and hold the `#` and `3`-buttons on your printer
   3. While holding, plug in the cable into the printer
   4. Continue holding for up to 20 seconds while the printer starts.
   5. Check if your issue is resolved. Try removing and inserting cadridges.
5. If that still doesn't work, do the same procedure as in 4, but hold down `6` instead of `3`. This should perform a deeper reset.
6. Do some resets from the factory access menu:

   1. Press `#` and `*` simultaneously while the printer is ON.
   2. `MFG Commands - Enter special key combo` should appear.
   3. Press `3`, `2`, `9` successively
   4. `uiaux - Service` should appear.
   5. Choose one of the available reset methods.
7. If that still doesn't work, you should try another ink cadridge. If it's showing the same problems, your printer is probably faulty, you should contact a HP service provider. If it works with that cadridge, you've probably been provided with a faulty cadridge. You could try to get your money back.